# Remove text when cell size is too small in d3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In the d3 treemap when a node has a very big value compared to others only the bigger node will be shown and others will not be visible or hidden. In some cases a small cell will be visible but the text margin will be cut off. How to remove the text when the cell is too small or make it responsive in d3 treemap.
My code is in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-treemap-new-n8tix?file=/src/treegraph.js
My code

```
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Treegraph extends React.Component {
  state = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };
  createTreeChart = () => {
    var width = 100, // % units for CSS responsiveness
      height = 100,
      snap = snap || 0.0001,
      x = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, width])
        .range([0, width]),
      y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, height])
        .range([0, height]),
      //blue = d3.hsl(216, 0.92, 0.68),,
      tile = (node, x0, y0, x1, y1) => {
        d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
        for (const child of node.children) {
          child.x0 = x0 + (child.x0 / width) * (x1 - x0);
          child.x1 = x0 + (child.x1 / width) * (x1 - x0);
          child.y0 = y0 + (child.y0 / height) * (y1 - y0);
          child.y1 = y0 + (child.y1 / height) * (y1 - y0);
        }
      },
      treemap = d3
        .treemap()
        .size([width, height])
        .tile(tile)
        .paddingInner(0)
        .round(false),
      data = {
        name: "SEGMENTS",
        columnName: "A",
        children: [
          {
            name: "A1 - subsection of a",
            columnName: "A",
            value: 2100,
            children: [
              {
                name: "B1 - subsection of b",
                columnName: "B",
                value: 520,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "C1  - subsection of C",
                    columnName: "C",
                    value: 85248197
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "B2 - subsection of b",
                columnName: "B",
                value: 500,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "C1 - subsection of c",
                    columnName: "C",
                    value: 500
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "A2 - subsection of a",
            columnName: "A",
            value: 2000,
            children: [
              {
                name: "B1 - subsection of a",
                columnName: "B",
                value: 1500,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "C1 - subsection of a",
                    columnName: "C",
                    value: 1248197
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "B2 - subsection of a",
                columnName: "B",
                value: 500,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "C1 - subsection of a",
                    columnName: "C",
                    value: 500
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      pathNames = [],
      nodes = d3
        .hierarchy(data)
        .sum(d => {
          return !d.children && d.value;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => !a.children && a.value - !b.children && b.value),
      resizeTimer,
      currentDepth;

    treemap(nodes);

    var chart = d3.select("#chart");
    var cells = chart
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.descendants())
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        // console.log("The d.depth function", d);
        return "node level-" + d.depth;
      })
      .attr("zndex", function(d) {
        // console.log("The d.depth function", d);
        return 110 - d.depth;
      })
      .attr("title", function(d) {
        return d.data.name ? `${d.data.name} (${d.data.value})` : "null";
      });

    cells
      //.style("transform", function(d) { return "translateY(" + chart.node().clientHeight * y(d.y0) / 100 + ")"; })
      .style("left", function(d) {
        //console.log( x(d.x0) + " => " + nearest(x(d.x0), snap) );
        return nearest(x(d.x0), snap) + "%";
      })
      .style("top", function(d) {
        // console.log(y(d.y0) + " => " + nearest(y(d.y0), snap));
        return nearest(y(d.y0), snap) + "%";
      })
      .style("width", function(d) {
        return nearest(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0), snap) + "%";
      })
      .style("height", function(d) {
        // console.log(
        //   y(d.y1) - y(d.y0) + " => " + nearest(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0), snap)
        // );
        return nearest(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0), snap) + "%";
      })
      .style("z-index", function(d) {
        // dynamic zindex for each node levels
        return d.data.name !== "SEGMENTS" && 110 - d.depth;
      })
      //.style("background-image", function(d) { return d.value ? imgUrl + d.value : ""; })
      .style("background-color", function(d) {
        return "orange";
      })
      .on("click", zoom);

    cells
      .append("p")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name ? d.data.name : "null";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
    var parent = d3
      .select(".logo")
      .datum(nodes)
      .on("click", zoom);

    // can't resquarify as we use 100*100% treemap size. Doh!
    d3.select(window).on("resize", function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(redraw, 250);
    });

    showPath(nodes.ancestors());

    function zoom(d) {
      // http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/amszcymq/

      // console.log("clicked: " + d.data.name + ", depth: " + d.depth);

      showPath(d.ancestors());

      currentDepth = d.depth;
      parent.datum(d.parent || nodes);

      x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
      y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

      var t = d3
        .transition()
        .duration(800)
        .ease(d3.easeCubicOut);

      cells
        .transition(t)
        .style("left", function(d) {
          return nearest(x(d.x0), snap) + "%";
        })
        .style("top", function(d) {
          return nearest(y(d.y0), snap) + "%";
        })
        .style("width", function(d) {
          return nearest(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0), snap) + "%";
        })
        .style("height", function(d) {
          return nearest(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0), snap) + "%";
        });

      cells // hide this depth and above
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.ancestors();
        })
        .classed("hide", function(d) {
          return d.children ? true : false;
        });

      cells // show this depth + 1 and below
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.depth > currentDepth;
        })
        .classed("hide", false);

      // if currentDepth == 3 show prev/next buttons
    }

    function redraw() {
      // console.log("window resized");

      treemap(nodes); //?
      //cells
      //    .datum(nodes)
      //    .call(zoom);
    }

    function showPath(p) {
      console.log("THE PATH", p);
      var path = d3
        .select(".breadcrumb")
        .selectAll("a")
        .data(
          p
            .map(function(d) {
              console.log("LOG the MAP FUNC", d);
              return d;
            })
            .reverse()
        );
      var path1 = d3
        .select(".breadcrumb")
        .selectAll("span")
        .data(
          p
            .map(function(d) {
              console.log("LOG the MAP FUNC", d);
              return d;
            })
            .reverse()
        );
      path.exit().remove();
      path1.exit().remove();

      console.log("THE PATHNAMES LOG", pathNames);
      path1
        .enter()
        .append("span")
        .attr("class", "activeNode")
        .html(function(d) {
          console.log("the d in second html", d);
          if (d.data.name !== "SEGMENTS" && d.data.children) {
            return ` <div> ${d.data.name} </div> <p class="right-symbol">></p>`;
          }
          if (!d.data.children) {
            return `<div > ${d.data.name} </div>`;
          }
        });
      path
        .enter()
        .append("a")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .html(function(d) {
          console.log("the d in html", d.data.columnName);
          return d.data.children && `${d.data.children[0].columnName} /`;
        })
        .on("click", zoom);
    }

    function nearest(x, n) {
      return n * Math.round(x / n);
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createTreeChart();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <nav>
          {/* <div class="logo"></div> */}
          <div className="breadcrumb" />
        </nav>
        <div className="feature" id="chart" />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Treegraph;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const containerHeight = d3
   .select(".feature")
   .node()
   .getBoundingClientRect().height;

const containerWidth = d3
   .select(".feature")
   .node()
   .getBoundingClientRect().width;

const allLabels = d3.selectAll(".label").nodes();

d3.selectAll(".label").style("display", (d, idx) => {
   const { width, height } = allLabels[idx].getBoundingClientRect();

   const parentWidth = (d.x1 - d.x0) * containerWidth / 100.0;
   const parentHeight = (d.y1 - d.y0) * containerHeight / 100.0;

   if (width > parentWidth || height > parentHeight) return "none";
   return "";
});
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue for some scenarios where in the width is too small

Comment: Then, you will need to get the text width, height and it's parent width, height, and compare them to show or hide text.